# Exchange 2010 - Open Other User Mailbox Permissions Issue

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010, shared-mailbox

I just started working for this small firm (30 people) a little bit ago, replacing their System Admin. First thing I noticed was Exchange Server 2010 was WAY out of date. Believe it or not they did not have SP1 installed. So after I installed and configured Exchange 2010 SP3 and redirected OWA I noticed something in OWA. I could add ANYONE's User Mailbox WITHOUT giving mailbox premission. I created a couple test users, same thing. I even had another employee provide me access to their OWA and they could open anyone's Inbox without granting permission. I don't want to play the blame game, but I was SHOCKED that this was going on. Luckly being such a small company I'll be able to cover this mistake that I did not create, BUT HOW?

My guess is that I need to find out where the past System Admin went wrong in providing Full Access Permission? Or could this be a Auto-Mapping issue?

I found this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529943.aspx

This might work `$FixAutoMapping = Get-MailboxPermission sharedmailbox |where {$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}
$FixAutoMapping | Remove-MailboxPermission
$FixAutoMapping | ForEach {Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User $_.User -AccessRights:FullAccess -AutoMapping $false}`

However how do I insert the above code into Powershell?

Again I was thrown into this mess and I'm just trying to iron out this tangled mess.

Comment: Don't know the answer I'm afraid but I'd recommend you don't try and hide the issue - at least once you have some ideas on how to fix it ;) It could easily come back to haunt you otherwise. It isn't your fault, make sure people understand that up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions for mailboxes are set at two different levels.  You can define permissions at the database level and at the mailbox level.  The mailboxes will inherit access right permissions from the database so I'd recommend you start there.  The powershell code to see who has rights and what those rights are at the database level is:

```
$Database = "your database name here"
Get-ADPermission $Database | Where-Object {$_.Deny -eq $False} | Select User,AccessRights
```

That code will give you a dump of who has DB rights (I'm betting "Everyone" or "Authenticated Users" has full access).  Use the `Add-ADPermission` and/or `Remove-ADPermission` cmdlets in order to re-mediate, remove, and change access rights.

Since you're new to Exchange administration, be extremely careful and use the `-Whatif` option where possible.  You may also want to consider bringing in an Exchange Administrator on a contract to look over your network and ensure configuration is correct and proper.

Comment: @BenjaminJones  I realized after the fact that there are some resources you'll find helpful.  The first is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124403(v=exchg.141).aspx which describes what the possible access rights are (expand the param tab).  And http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638132(v=exchg.141).aspx for greater detail of permissions.